# in flutter mvvm :why screen shaking when open it?

Tags: flutter, mvvm

when open this screen and other screen , this screen is shaking ,
In Flutter,  a screen is shaking or flickering when navigating between screens, please help me for resolve this problem ,

in this view using StatelessWidget  ,i'm used StatefullWidget in another views, there same problem when use StatefullWidget
in view:

```
import ...............


class SettingView extends StatelessWidget {
 const SettingView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   var languageProvider = Provider.of<LanguageProvider>(context, listen: true);
   var viewmodel =
       Provider.of<SettingsViewModelProvider>(context, listen: true);
   final ConnectivityProvider connectivityProvider =
       Provider.of<ConnectivityProvider>(context);
   Provider.of<LanguageProvider>(context, listen: false).getLan();
   var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
   const int currentIndex = 0;
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: ColorManager.backgroundScafoald,
     body: SafeArea(
       child: Container(
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Stack(
               children: [
                 fixedHeaderWidget(size, context, languageProvider),
               ],
             ),
             Expanded(
               child: Column(
                 children: [
                   listViewItem(context, languageProvider,
                       languageProvider.getTexts('AddYourModuls'), () async {
                     if (viewmodel.getM == ListScreenStateModules.initial) {
                       bool isConnected =
                           await connectivityProvider.isConnected();
                       if (isConnected) {
                         WidgetFunctionHelper.loadingupload(context);
                         await viewmodel.fetchModulesList().then((value) {
                           Navigator.pop(context);
                         });
                         Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.listModuilsRoute,
                             arguments: {
                               'listModules': viewmodel.listmoduleModel
                             });
                       } else {
                         WidgetFunctionHelper.showErrorSnackbar(
                             context,
                             languageProvider.getTexts('NoInternet'),
                             languageProvider.getTexts('cancel'));
                       }
                     }
                     if (viewmodel.getM == ListScreenStateModules.error) {
                       WidgetFunctionHelper.showErrorSnackbar(
                           context,
                           viewmodel.errorMessages,
                           languageProvider.getTexts('cancel'));
                       viewmodel.setStategetM(ListScreenStateModules.initial);
                     } else if (viewmodel.getM ==
                         ListScreenStateModules.loaded) {
                       viewmodel.setStategetM(ListScreenStateModules.initial);
                     } else {
                       viewmodel.setStategetM(ListScreenStateModules.initial);
                     }
                   },
                       AssetImage(
                         ImageAsset.moduls,
                       )),
                   listViewItem(context, languageProvider,
                       languageProvider.getTexts('AddYourGroups'), () {
                     Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.listGroupesRoute);
                   },
                       AssetImage(
                         ImageAsset.groups,
                       )),
                   listViewItem(
                       context,
                       languageProvider,
                       languageProvider.getTexts('EditPassword'),
                       () {},
                       AssetImage(
                         ImageAsset.editpass,
                       )),
                   listViewItem(context, languageProvider,
                       languageProvider.getTexts('Logout'), () async {
                     WidgetFunctionHelper.loadingupload(context);
                     await Future.delayed(Duration(
                         seconds: 2)); // Adjust the duration as needed
                     await viewmodel.logout(context).then((value) {
                       Navigator.pop(context);
                       Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                           context, Routes.splashRoute);
                     });
                   },
                       AssetImage(
                         ImageAsset.logout,
                       )),
                 ],
               ),
             )
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
     bottomNavigationBar: const NavigationBottomBar(
       selectedIndex: currentIndex,
     ),
   );
 }


 static Widget listViewItem(
     BuildContext context,
     LanguageProvider languageProvider,
     String name,
     Function() func,
     AssetImage img) {
   return Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p12),
     child: SizedBox(
       height: AppSize.s90,
       width: double.infinity,
       child: Card(
         color: ColorManager.white,
         shape:
             RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Padding(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p20),
               child: Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                 children: [
                   Center(
                     child: Text(
                       name,
                       style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.educonecth,
                     ),
                   ),
                   InkWell(
                     onTap: func,
                     highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                     splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                     child: Container(
                         height: 30,
                         width: 30,
                         child: Image(
                           color: ColorManager.green,
                           image: img,
                         )),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 Container fixedHeaderWidget(
     Size size, BuildContext context, LanguageProvider languageProvider) {
   return Container(
     height: size.height * AppSize.s0_2,
     child: Stack(
       children: [
         Container(
           height: size.height * AppSize.s0_2 - AppSize.s40,
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(
             left: languageProvider.lang == 'ar'
                 ? AppPadding.p20
                 : AppPadding.p0,
             right: languageProvider.lang == 'ar'
                 ? AppPadding.p0
                 : AppPadding.p20,
           ),
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: ColorManager.primary,
           ),
         ),
         Positioned(
             right: languageProvider.lang == 'ar' ? AppSize.s12 : AppSize.s12,
             left: languageProvider.lang == 'ar' ? AppSize.s12 : AppSize.s12,
             child: const Image(
               image: AssetImage(
                 ImageAsset.logoApp,
               ),
               width: AppSize.s150,
               height: AppSize.s150,
             )),
         Positioned(
           top: AppSize.s70,
           left: AppSize.s0,
           right: AppSize.s0,
           child: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Padding(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: AppPadding.p20),
               child: SizedBox(
                 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                 child: Column(
                   children: [
                     const SizedBox(height: AppSize.s18),
                     Container(
                       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           color: ColorManager.green,
                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                       child: Column(
                         children: [
                           Padding(
                               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppPadding.p5),
                               child: Text(
                                 languageProvider.getTexts('settingsAccess'),
                                 style:
                                     Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                               )),
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

in viewModel:

```
import ...............

enum ListScreenStates { initial, loading, loaded, error }

enum ListScreenStateModules { initial, loading, loaded, error }

class SettingsViewModelProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
 ListScreenStates state = ListScreenStates.initial;
 late String errorMessages;

 late ApiResult apiResult;
 bool isSelected = false;

 Future<void> logout(context) async {
   await Future.delayed(
       const Duration(microseconds: AppConstants.onBordingOneDelay));

   await SharedPreferencesHelper.removeTokenAuth();
   await SharedPreferencesHelper.removeLoggedIn();
   await SharedPreferencesHelper.removeToken();
   await SharedPreferencesHelper.removeInfoTeacher();
   await SharedPreferencesHelper.removeHasData();
   await SharedPreferencesHelper.removeHasGroups();
   await SharedPreferencesHelper.removeHasModule();
 }

 setStateS(state) {
   this.state = state;
   notifyListeners();
 }

 String fname = '';
 String lname = '';
 String email = '';
 getINfoTacher() async {
   fname = await SharedPreferencesHelper.getFname();
   lname = await SharedPreferencesHelper.getLname();
   email = await SharedPreferencesHelper.getEmail();
   notifyListeners();
 }

 /* ###########
 ##############
 "###########
  ################ */

 ListScreenStateModules getM = ListScreenStateModules.initial;

 final List<ModuleModel> _listmoduleModel = [];

 List<ModuleModel> get listmoduleModel => _listmoduleModel;
 Future<void> fetchModulesList() async {
   setStategetM(ListScreenStateModules.loading);

   final apiResult = await ModuleService().getModules();

   if (!apiResult.hasError) {
     final moduls = apiResult.data['subjects'] as List<dynamic>;
     _listmoduleModel.clear();
     for (int i = 0; i < moduls.length; i++) {
       final item = moduls[i];
       final List<String> types = (item['type'] as List)
           .cast<String>(); // Extract 'type' as a List<String>
       _listmoduleModel.add(
         ModuleModel(
           name: item['name'] as String,
           id: item['_id'] as String,
           types: types,
         ),
       );
     }
     setStategetM(ListScreenStateModules.loaded);

     notifyListeners();
   } else {
     errorMessages = apiResult.failure.message;
     setStategetM(ListScreenStateModules.error);
   }
 }

 setStategetM(getM) {
   this.getM = getM;
   notifyListeners();
 }
}
```